# Nearby Connection 2.0: Identify endpoint over reconnection

Tags: android, google-nearby

Is there a way to uniquely identify a discovered endpoint and persist that information over reconnection?
Apparently the endpointId changes after a disconnection.
If I correctly recall, in the former api there was a persistent identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nearby Connections doesn't support reconnections yet, but you can encode a persistent id in your endpoint name (eg. endpointName="1234:Will").

Please note that the endpoint name can be spoofed, so if you need a secure connection you need to either compare the auth token or do some more authentication after accepting the connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll use the endpointName for the moment. But it would be great to have a persistent id for endpoints (even if it is only during the discoverer lifecycle).

Comment: Yup, agreed. I have a note written down somewhere to add that eventually (with proper authenticated reconnections), but it hasn't been a priority.